# an algorithm problem about the control of switchs

Tags: algorithm, switch-statement

Could you help me to solve the problem below...

There is a N*M table, and each cell has a switch which has two states --- ON/OFF.
When we are changing the state of one switch, not only itself but also the up,down,left and right are changed.
The problem is to write a program to find out and print the least steps to turn off all the switches. If not, print -1.

For example, below is a 3*4 table.
(※● is OFF and O is ON.)

*pic.1*

```
●   ●   ●   ●
●   O   ●   ●
●   ●   ●   ●
```

Now we change the (1,1) cell from ON to OFF, and then the table will be changed to the below.

*pic.2*

```
●   O   ●   ●
O   ●   O   ●
●   O   ●   ●
```

And when we change the (0,2) cell from OFF to ON, it will become to :

*pic.3*

```
●   ●   O   O
O   ●   ●   ●
●   O   ●   ●
```

and so on...

By the way, the result for this example(*pic.1*) is 4. It means at least 4 steps are required to change all of the switches to OFF.

I have implemented the problem using javascript and commited it to github.

[enter link description here](https://github.com/yuukama/switchstatuschange)

Comment: It seems you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: The problem is to write a program to find out and print the least steps to turn off all the switches. If not, print -1.

Comment: @nullpointexception, Henry meant where are you stuck?

Comment: @nullpointexception As far as I see your problem statement, there will never be a finished state.

Comment: Sorry my English isn't 100%fluent. I have no idea about it , the code is a playable version for discribe the algorithm quiz.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lights_Out_(game) ?

Comment: Thank you very much. It is Lights_Out. This is very important clue for me.

Comment: 2nd clue:  When you see "minimum steps" it should suggest "breadth-first search"

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will take a look at "breadth-first search".

Answer (score 0):

### Provide a First-Stab Solution

It's fine to post a link to your sample code, but you should reference it and then provide a first-stab solution. Explain why you're having trouble, or what issues you have.

### Algorithms and Board State

Your goal is to find a path where toggling cells leads to a winning state. I see that you've coded a playable version, but no automatic search logic.

Take a look at [A* search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) for some tips. In addition to an attempt routine, you'll need a way to compare board states. You know if you've reached the winning condition, but search algorithms tend to need a heuristic as well. You could use the heuristic that "fewer on pins is better" to get started.

Comment: Thanks very much. But I have no idea about it up to now . I will take a look at A* search for some tips. Thank you again.